# Grouping search queries by similarity of search results

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

we run some studies using google search queries.

We need to cluster these queries in topics and we would like to find some unsupervised approach.

for each query we have the search results.

I thought to use the number of urls in common as discriminants.
Other discriminants could be the text similarity of queries and of titles of the results.

Since i'm quite new to clustering could you suggest me some approach?

Description and justification of the algorithm (and if possible implementation in R) is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe topic modeling is better suited than clustering?

Comment: More info about it and the difference between the two?

Comment: Google for it. Topics is designed for text, while most clustering methods are designed for dense "point" vectors with Euclidean distance.